# Управление игроком с помощью касаний через Input.touches[0] выдаёт исключение Array index is out of range

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-android, unity3d-ui

Есть такой скрипт, который помогает управлять моим игроком через касания. Вот код скрипта:

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class JoystickControl : MonoBehaviour, IDragHandler, IEndDragHandler, IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler
{

private enum AxisOption { HorizontalAndVertical, Horizontal, Vertical }
private enum ControlMode { AnalogStick, DirectionalPad }
private enum ProjectMode { Project3D, Project2D };
[SerializeField] private AxisOption axes;
[SerializeField] private ControlMode mode;
[SerializeField] private ProjectMode project;
public static Vector3 direction { get; private set; }

void Awake()
{
    direction = Vector3.zero;
}

Vector2 Round(Vector2 val)
{
    float x = Mathf.Abs(val.x);
    float y = Mathf.Abs(val.y);

    if (x >= 0.5f && y >= 0.5f)
    {
        val.x = Mathf.Sign(val.x);
        val.y = Mathf.Sign(val.y);
        return val;
    }

    if (x > y)
    {
        val.x = Mathf.Sign(val.x);
        val.y = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        val.x = 0;
        val.y = Mathf.Sign(val.y);
    }

    return val;
}

void UpdateDirection()
{
    Vector2 curDir = new Vector2(Input.touches[0].position.x - transform.position.x, Input.touches[0].position.y - transform.position.y).normalized;
    if (mode == ControlMode.DirectionalPad) curDir = Round(curDir);
    if (axes == AxisOption.Horizontal) curDir = new Vector2(Mathf.Sign(curDir.x), 0);
    else if (axes == AxisOption.Vertical) curDir = new Vector2(0, Mathf.Sign(curDir.y));
    if (project == ProjectMode.Project3D) direction = new Vector3(curDir.x, 0, curDir.y); else direction = new Vector3(curDir.x, curDir.y, 0);
}

public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    UpdateDirection();
}

public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    UpdateDirection();
}

public void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    direction = Vector3.zero;
}

public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    direction = Vector3.zero;
}
}
```

На сцене в канвасе у меня есть объект Image на котором включен Raycast Target, следом висит этот скрипт. В скрипте PlayerController, который управляет игроком, я вызываю в FixedUpdate это:

```
body.AddForce(JoystickControl.direction * _speed);
```

В скрипте JoystickControl в инспекторе я выставляю настройки (показано на картинке ниже)
[image: Скрин из проекта]

Далее при запуске игры начинает сыпаться одна и так же ошибка. Количество выпадения этой ошибки зависит от того, как долго и сколько раз я пытался нажать на экран.
[image: Ошибка Array index is out of range]

Вот собственно сама строчка 49, к которой ведёт ошибка
[image: Фрагмент кода]

Как решить данную проблему, помогите)

Comment: Вы бы сначала разобрались со своим предыдущим вопросом, прежде чем задавать новый. Такими темпами люди принципиально не будут отвечать.

Answer (score 0):

Все очень просто, перед тем как работать с `Input.touches[]` предварительно проверьте что он не пустой, поскольку в момент когда касаний нет в нем не будет `0` элемента к которому вы обращаетесь

Comment: нее, проблема появляется именно когда нажатие происходит. Когда нажатия нет, ошибок тоже нет. Но как я касаюсь экрана, начинает сыпаться эта ошибка, до тех пор, пока я не отпущу палец. То есть проблема тут не в том, что массив не имеет 0 элемента. Мой персонаж не двигается совсем...

Comment: `"...проблема тут не в том, что массив не имеет 0 элемента"`

  Однако код ошибки говорит об обратном.

Comment: Движение у вас выполняется в другом коде. Тот что вы привели только меняет состояние ввода, причем коряво. `UpdateDirection` вызывается только когда вы первый раз нажали на экран или только начали двигать объект.

Answer (score 0):

```
void UpdateDirection()
{
    if(Input.touches[0]>0)
    {
        Vector2 curDir = new Vector2(Input.touches[0].position.x - transform.position.x, Input.touches[0].position.y - transform.position.y).normalized;
        if (mode == ControlMode.DirectionalPad) curDir = Round(curDir);

        if (axes == AxisOption.Horizontal) curDir = new Vector2(Mathf.Sign(curDir.x), 0);
        else if (axes == AxisOption.Vertical) curDir = new Vector2(0, Mathf.Sign(curDir.y));

        if (project == ProjectMode.Project3D) direction = new Vector3(curDir.x, 0, curDir.y); else direction = new Vector3(curDir.x, curDir.y, 0);
    }
}
```